# Divison operator in a miles/kilometer conversion programme

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I'm writing a simple miles to kilometer programme, where the user enters in miles and the programme shows the conversion result. I've been instructed to use integers, and this is what I have written:

```
{Console.Write("Enter distance in miles");
string input1 = Console.ReadLine();
int number1 = Convert.ToInt32 (input1);
int result1 = number1 / 0.65;
Console.Write(number1 + "Miles is equal to " + result1 + "KM");
Console.ReadLine();
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Can anyone help and let me know why I'm getting this error? I'm a complete beginner :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The division `number1 / 0.65` is an expression of type `double`, even when `number1` is an `int`.

The error already suggests to do a type-cast, it looks like:

```
int result1 = (int) (number1 / 0.65);
```

Answer (score 1):

In C#, an integer divided by a double returns a double, and `0.65` is a `double` literal. Your line `int result1 = number1 / 0.65;` is thus trying to turn a double into an integer without an explicit cast.

The quick solution to that is to add an explicit cast:

```
int result1 = (int)(number1 / 0.65);
```

But you should be aware that this will effectively truncate the decimal (take the mathematical floor). You might want to wrap this in rounding, for your application.

```
int result1 = (int)Math.Round(number1 / 0.65);
```